# Google Cloud Virtual instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, cloud, instance

I am learning GCP by my own, created instance with ubuntu OS I turned on UFW on ubuntu add 80and 443 but forgot to enable SSH 22 port and now I am not able to connect it by SSH, please help me out I dont want to lose my server configuration. I dont want to delete this instance  please help me out,

Thank in Advance.

is there any chance from google power Shell option?

Comment: I wrote an article that should help you: https://www.jhanley.com/blog/google-cloud-recovering-from-ufw-lockout/

Answer (score 0):

it was quire simple if you have same issue then please follow steps given below

1. Shut down the instance
2. Click 'Edit' for the instance
3. Under 'Custom Metadata' section, add 'startup-script' key, with
   value: sudo ufw allow 22
4. "save" the instance and Start it.